# MqttNet Basic example

Tags: c#, wpf, mqtt

I have to create a very basic Mqtt broker-client demo
I have therefore followed and downloaded [this](https://dev.to/eduardojuliao/basic-mqtt-with-c-1f88) example.

It works perfectly but it is a console application with Net5.0.

I have to make it work on a wpf 4.5.2. solution.
That should be possible according to this
[image]

So taking as example the solution above

[image]

I have created a project of my own with the same referencies

[image]

Per each project I have also added the correct using statements as in the example.

So everything should be correct but when I paste the code for the Server I get those errors

```
MqttServerOptionsBuilder options = new MqttServerOptionsBuilder()
           .WithDefaultEndpoint()
           .WithDefaultEndpointPort(707)
           .WithConnectionValidator(OnNewConnection)
           .WithApplicationMessageInterceptor(OnNewMessage);


        IMqttServer mqttServer = new MqttFactory().CreateMqttServer();
```

[image]

and also for the client I get other errors

[image]

Where is the problem?
Thanks

---ADD---

As requested here are the errors

```
(1) Error   CS1061  'IManagedMqttClient' does not contain a definition for 'ConnectedHandler' and no accessible extension method 'ConnectedHandler' accepting a first argument of type 'IManagedMqttClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Client  C:\Development\MqttDemo\MqttDemo\Client\MainWindow.xaml.cs  43  25  IntelliSense    Active

(2) Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'MqttClientConnectedHandlerDelegate' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Client  C:\Development\MqttDemo\MqttDemo\Client\MainWindow.xaml.cs  43  48  IntelliSense    Active

(3) Error   CS0103  The name 'OnConnected' does not exist in the current context    Client  C:\Development\MqttDemo\MqttDemo\Client\MainWindow.xaml.cs  43  83  IntelliSense    Active

(4) Error   CS1061  'IManagedMqttClient' does not contain a definition for 'DisconnectedHandler' and no accessible extension method 'DisconnectedHandler' accepting a first argument of type 'IManagedMqttClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  Client  C:\Development\MqttDemo\MqttDemo\Client\MainWindow.xaml.cs  44  25  IntelliSense    Active

(5) Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'MqttClientDisconnectedHandlerDelegate' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Client  C:\Development\MqttDemo\MqttDemo\Client\MainWindow.xaml.cs  44  51  IntelliSense    Active

(6) Error   CS0103  The name 'OnDisconnected' does not exist in the current context Client  C:\Development\MqttDemo\MqttDemo\Client\MainWindow.xaml.cs  44  89  IntelliSense    Active

(7) Error   CS1061  'IManagedMqttClient' does not contain a definition for 'ConnectingFailedHandler' and no accessible extension method 'ConnectingFailedHandler' accepting a first argument of type 'IManagedMqttClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  Client  C:\Development\MqttDemo\MqttDemo\Client\MainWindow.xaml.cs  45  25  IntelliSense    Active

(8) Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ConnectingFailedHandlerDelegate' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Client  C:\Development\MqttDemo\MqttDemo\Client\MainWindow.xaml.cs  45  55  IntelliSense    Active

(9) Error   CS0103  The name 'OnConnectingFailed' does not exist in the current context Client  C:\Development\MqttDemo\MqttDemo\Client\MainWindow.xaml.cs  45  87  IntelliSense    Active

(10) Error  CS1061  'IManagedMqttClient' does not contain a definition for 'ApplicationMessageReceivedHandler' and no accessible extension method 'ApplicationMessageReceivedHandler' accepting a first argument of type 'IManagedMqttClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  Client  C:\Development\MqttDemo\MqttDemo\Client\MainWindow.xaml.cs  47  25  IntelliSense    Active

(11) Error  CS0246  The type or namespace name 'MqttApplicationMessageReceivedHandlerDelegate' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Client  C:\Development\MqttDemo\MqttDemo\Client\MainWindow.xaml.cs  47  65  IntelliSense    Active

(12) Error  CS1061  'IManagedMqttClient' does not contain a definition for 'PublishAsync' and no accessible extension method 'PublishAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'IManagedMqttClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Client  C:\Development\MqttDemo\MqttDemo\Client\MainWindow.xaml.cs  56  29  IntelliSense    Active
```

Comment: Please attempt to compile the code and give us the errors output (as formatted text) instead of screenshots from your IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MQTT is fast becoming one of the main protocols for IOT (internet of things) deployments.

*There are two different variants of MQTT and several versions.*

MQTT v3.1.0 –

MQTT v3.1.1 – In Common Use

MQTT v5 – Currently Limited use

MQTT-SN – See notes later

The example you follow use version *3.0.16*. MQTT v3.1.1 is version in common use. There is very little difference between v3.10 and 3.1.1. so downgrade your MQTT to solve this problem.

```
Install-Package MQTTnet -Version 3.0.16
```

Client:

```
Install-Package MQTTnet.Extensions.ManagedClient -Version 3.0.16
```

ref: [link1](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mqtt/), [link2](https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.org/wiki/Differences-between-3.1.0-and-3.1.1), [link3](http://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2016/september/article3.php), [link4](https://mqtt.org/getting-started/)

Comment: You sir are without any doubt my hero! You saved my job :-) Thanks a million

Comment: This couldn't be a more incorrect answer. You only helped the OP by bare luck. The problem is the samples are for MQTTnet 3.x not 4.x, the problem is completely unrelated to the version of the MQTT protocol being used.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Here I am talking about 'two different variants of MQTT and several versions.' not protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You were trying to use MQTTNet new version 4.0.1.184 with old version 3.1.x samples.

If you want to use latest MQTTNet (4.x) version then use latest samples. Like the one from their github page - https://github.com/dotnet/MQTTnet/blob/master/Samples/Client/Client_Subscribe_Samples.cs

MQTTNet (client) version is not related to MQTT (protocol) version and as far as know they are interoperable. I.e. MQTT 3.1.1 can be used with MQTTNet 4.x clients.